# How do I load custom template for password reset?

Tags: django

I'm setting up a Django project that will have a custom password reset form.

My paths look like this:

```
MY_PROJECT
 -myBlog
  -myBlog
   -urls.py
  -theme
   -templates
    -pages
     -password_reset_form.html
```

My `urls.py` has this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
urlpatterns += [
    url("^reset-password/$", auth_views.password_reset, 
        {
            "template_name": "pages/password_reset_form.html"
        },
        name="reset_pw"
    ),
]
```

When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/password_reset/`, it loads Django's default password reset form. I want it to load my template. How do I set things up so my form loads instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be from either the views.py or because you wrote

```
127.0.0.1:8000/password_reset/
...instead of 
localhost:8000/password-reset/
```

As defined in you url pattern